# WSO2 API Manager 3.2 - rewrite resources

Tags: url-rewriting, resources, wso2-api-manager

I would like to rewrite parameters in the resources of APIs in publisher.

I need to rewrite resource /question?$top=parameter1&$select=parameter2&$filter=parameter3 to /question/parameter3?$top=parameter1&$select=parameter2.

Could you please advise?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the resource by editing the relevant Swagger definition. Navigate to the `API Definition` section in the left panel in Publisher Portal, edit the resource and update the Swagger definition with the required changes to the resource.

As per the question, you need to add `paramter3` as path parameter and remove one query parameter. You can use the following swagger segment to set path parameter to the resource.

```yaml
      parameters: 
      - name: parameter3
        in: path
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
```

Comment: This doesn't resolve my problem. Could somebody help me with this? I thought that mediators might be used for this purpose. Could you please help me with what mediator I could use and how to use them?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you need to convert the `parameter3` as path parameter instead of query parameter when passing to the backend and expose it as `/question?$top=parameter1&$select=parameter2&$filter=parameter3` to the end user?